# Unable to send JSON object over "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, json, rest, post

Having a strange problem.

I have an object

```
const otherParams = {
  hello: "world"
};

const params = {
  payload: JSON.stringify(otherParams);
  apiKey: 1234,
  hmac: 13414
}
```

I've used the npm package `querystring` to encode `params` as well

```
// post method here

url: "https://endpoint.com",
method: "POST",
query: querystring.stringify(params),
headers: {
  "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

Its all fine and dandy but the problem is the `payload` is not being sent, is this an issue with `querystring` being unable to encode `payload`?

[image: form data]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full code listing? `querystring` or `post method` might be having an effect.

Comment: Actually what i noticed is only after sending a stringified JSON object to the endpoint, the data does not show

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
url: "https://endpoint.com",
method: "POST",
query: querystring.stringify(params),
headers: {
  "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","application/json"
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if multiple headers for `"Content-type"` are allowed, do you know how to implement this ?